# Express.js App no Response on localhost:3000

Tags: express

I created an `express.js` app by typing the following the commands in (OSX):

```
$ express mytestapp<br>
$ cd mytestapp<br>
$ npm install
```

Then when I type code below

```
$ node app.js
```

and I navigate to `http://localhost:3000`  I get this webpage is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An express4 app that's generated using the generator is no longer started using `node app.js` but instead using;

```
npm start
```

[The relevant section of the docs](http://expressjs.com/migrating-4.html#app-gen).